# Android: How to pass data of one activity with the button click in another activity

Tags: android, database, android-intent, buttonclick

I have two classes like firstactivity.java and secondactivity.java. In firstactivity  I have a button(submit)  when I click the button(submit) I want to pass the data of firstactivity.java to server. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `FirstActivity.java` file `onclick` button you should used below code.

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
i1.putExtra("type", "edit");
startActivity(i1);
```

In `secondActivity.java` file oncreate .. used below code.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Strinjg Value = extras.getSerializable("type").toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add things to a bundle and add the bundle to the intent.

Then read the bundle in the new activity and get what you need from it. There should be hundreds of posts on Google and SO about this.

Comment: You commented 42 seconds after my post... Did you even search or read anything about my answer in that time? Quit being lazy... read some docs and learn something instead of asking everyone to do your work...

Comment: And now he deletes his comment asking me for code... What a putz

Comment: Click on Raghu's profile and look at his questions. He doesnt write any of his own code... He just lets everyone write it for him... If you keep giving answer to people like this with no understanding, you will only get worse and worse apps for the platform.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass data from one activity to another activity by using this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(firstactivty.class,secondactivity.class);
i.putExtra("String","abc");
startActivity(i);
```

And you can get this data to secondActivity by using this:

```
Bundle extras;
extras =getIntent().getExtras();
string value=extras.getString("String");
```

But remember one thing: keyword would be same when you pass the data as well as getdata, for example:

```
i.putExtra("String","abc"); //pass value
extras.getString("String"); //get value
```

Answer (score 2):

First send the second activity data to your first activity using intents,then get that data in First Activity using getIntent() method or you can store those data in static fields then you can get the data wherever you want

Answer (score 2):

For passing data between activities you could use set extra methods of intent which you use for starting activity [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29)

Also you can use [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to pass data between parts of you program

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("int-value",10); // put data to bundle
int value = bundle.getInt("int-value",0); // gets value from bundle, or 0 (second parameter)
```

You can return data from second activity to first using method [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

```
// Somewhere in your activity
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra("result-value",10);
setResult(RESULT_OK,result);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the putExtra(String name, Bundle value) method of Intent class to send data to second activity. Get this data in second activity from a Bundle object's getExtra() method.