# How can I reach one activity's Intent from an another?

Tags: android, android-intent

If I make for example an

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
 b.putString("Number", spinner.getSelectedItem);
 i.putExtras(b);
```

So If I want to reach this intent from an another activity, how Can I do this?

Comment: Intents are passed when you start the other activity with `startActivity(i);`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Please check below link more helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592441/android-how-to-pass-data-of-one-activity-with-the-button-click-in-another-activi/6592507#6592507

Comment: What you are asking is not clear- do you want to access this intent from an activity started with this intent, or from a different activity altogether?

Comment: My problem is, that I don't want to start the activity from here. I want to make a settings tab in real, and from it I want to use a spinner, and from it I want to use the selected item in the another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In Android: How do I get variables/data from one screen to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347152/in-android-how-do-i-get-variables-data-from-one-screen-to-another)

In the onCreate in your second activity you would get the string by calling:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("Number");
```